# Is it possible to clone / branch a saga which previously threw an exception

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, generator, redux-saga

I am writing a test for a saga that has a branch of code that executes if there is an error in an API call.  This error handling code triggers a different workflow depending on the current redux state.

I am also using `cloneableGenerator` to test different branches so I don't have to repeat all of the previous steps.  However, it seems that when creating a clone from another clone which previously threw an error, the previous steps that the new clone executes to bring it current with the first clone's state, does not execute the same thrown error...

**Example:**

```
// saga.ts
import { SagaIterator } from 'redux-saga';
import { select } from 'redux-saga/effects';

export function* foo(): SagaIterator {
  try {
    // do some stuff...

    // make call to API...
  } catch (e) {
    const bar = yield select(getBar);
    if (bar) {
      // execute workflow 1
    } else {
      // execute workflow 2
    }
  }
}

// saga.spec.ts
import { cloneableGenerator, SagaIteratorClone } from 'redux-saga/utils';
import { foo } from 'saga.ts'

describe('foo saga', () => {
  let gen: SagaIteratorClone;

  beforeAll(() => {
    fooGen = cloneableGenerator(foo)();
  });

  test('should do some stuff and make an API call', () => {
    // test steps before API call
  });

  describe('when the API call succeeds', () => {
    let apiSuccessClone: SagaIteratorClone;

    beforeAll(() => {
      apiSuccessClone = fooGen.clone();
    });

    // ... success logic tests go here...
  }

  describe('when the API call fails', () => {
    let apiFailClone: SagaIteratorClone;

    beforeAll(() => {
      apiFailClone = fooGen.clone();
      apiFailClone.throw!();
    });

    test('should check bar state', () => {
      const actual = apiFailClone.next().value;
      const expected = select(getBar);
      expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
    });

    describe('if bar exists', () => {
      let barExistsClone: SagaIteratorClone;

      beforeAll(() => {
        barExistsClone = apiFailClone.clone(); // <-- THIS DOES NOT WORK
      });
    });
  });
});
```

When calling `apiFailClone.clone()` and stepping-through the actual `foo` generator code, the catch-up steps taken by the new clone do not mirror the `throw()` call and so the new clone executes the 'API call success' branch rather than the 'API call failed' version...

So, TLDR; is there a way to accomplish what I want using clones, or am I going to have to make a separate test that manually re-executes all the previous steps to fully test the logic within the `catch` block?